# Type narrowing not working when using Omit

Tags: typescript

An example setup:

```js
type A = {
  type: 'A';
  foo: string;
  baz: number;
}

type B = {
  type: 'B';
  bar: string;
  baz: number;
}

type Unioned = A | B
```

This works fine:

```js
function handle(x:Unioned) {
  if (x.type === 'A') {
    console.log(x.foo)
  }
}
```

However, I get an error with this:

```js
function handle(x:Omit<Unioned, 'baz'>) {
  if (x.type === 'A') {
    console.log(x.foo)
  }
}
```

Specifically, the error I get is: `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Omit<Unioned, "baz">'`.

I would expect that typescript can infer the type of `x` within the if statement is actually `Omit<A, 'baz'>`, but it doesn't.

What is it about using `Omit` that causes this to happen? And how can I make this work as expected?

Comment: The problem is that `Omit<T>` does not *distribute* across unions in `T`.  You need to use a distributive version of `Omit` if you want to use it with unions, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAd2QN).  Please see the answers to the questions linked above for more information.